# Do youtube account IDs, playlist IDs or video IDs automatically change or update periodically?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm currently doing some work with the youtube api.

One of the solutions which i'm planning to use for storing video information for future reference is to store the video ID's and playlist ID's.

Will this work or will the ID's change at some point and render my keys useless?

Comment: IDs are unique identifiers and do not change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know Video IDs don't change. I have a SQL Server database that stores my organization's YouTube videos metadata. This saves on YouTube quota usage.

Comment: That is almost exaclty what i'm planning to do. Thank you for the response